Mounted usb drive gets Operation not permitted on write
My mounted usb drive gets Operation not permitted when I write to it:
$ sudo touch /Volumes/NO\ NAME/aaa
touch: cannot touch '/Volumes/NO NAME/aaa': Operation not permitted

$ mount | grep NO
/dev/disk4s1 on /Volumes/NO NAME (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners, noatime, fskit)

$ sw_vers
ProductName:            macOS
ProductVersion:         14.4.1
BuildVersion:           23E224

What's the fix?
More info:
Following https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlf779ae93/mac, my "Allow accessories to connect” is now Always:

Following https://iboysoft.com/ntfs-for-mac/usb-drive-read-only-mac.html, my USB drive does not contain any unknown errors:

and writable:

and Sharing & Permissions looks good to me too:


Do you have the same problem if you use a different computer (Mac or PC)?

It looks like you haven't stored anything on the volume yet. Rather than beating your head against this mystery, I suggest you reformat it as ExFAT if you need cross-platform compatibility.

No Allan, I tried it on my Linux machine first (tested with dd) and it works just fine. Ok @LincD., I'll try reformatting it but I doubt that I'll get Operation not permitted too...

Please post the results.

Error: -69877: Couldn't open device @LincD.

This is going to get tedious, but you should boot in safe mode and try again, and if that fails, try it in Recovery mode. If that fails as well, then you're dealing with a fault in the drive, the port, or the cable (if there is one.) Also, you should repartition the drive, not just reformat the volume.
